RestSharp requests became working when I intercept them with Fiddler Everywhere
There's a ridiculous problem.
I send a POST request to an API and it goes smoothly with programs like Postman/Bruno. But with libraries like RestSharp/Flurl/HttpClient, I was getting 400 responses.
Today, while analyzing requests with Fiddler Everywhere, I saw that this RestSharp request works fine. In other words, the C# RestSharp request goes smoothly without getting a 400 error when intercepting.
What could be the reason for this?

Could you provide an example request? It seems that your requests have a problem (e.g. encoding) which the tools mentioned  are „fixing“ (there‘s an old article by @EricLaw about that at https://www.telerik.com/blogs/help!-running-fiddler-fixes-my-app-.

If an identical request works/fails just by changing the client (or the proxy) then most likely the server performs TLS fingerprinting to identify the used TLS library/programming framework. If you get an HTTP 400 the TLS library is black-listed by the server.

I am added ‘Connection’ header and set value to ‘keep-alive’ then worked like a charm. But only in HttpClient. RestSharp/Flurl not working.
